# Passing a nested list into a function and getting a nested list

Tags: python, python-3.x

** Based on `Marcus.Aurelianus` response, I have modified the question and executed the following code

```
def Bigfunction(G,T):
    return list(map(lambda x,y:10**-3*x*(1 + (y-25)),G,T)),list(map(lambda x,y:(x/1000)*(1 + (y-25)),G,T)), list(map(lambda x:(x/800),G))
G = list(range(100,1100,100))
T = list(range(25,40,10))
Iph_cal, Isc_cal, Tcel_cal = Bigfunction(G,T)
print(Iph_cal, Isc_cal, Tcel_cal)
```

**Output is:

```
[0.07000999999999999, 0.14464065999999998] [0.06999999999999999, 0.14461999999999997] [28.5, 32.0, 35.5, 39.0, 42.5, 46.0, 49.5, 53.0, 56.5, 60.0]
```

** In output: first and second list have given two elements only. Where as third list has given 10 elements, which is correct. Why the first and second list are not producing 10 elements.

Comment: The syntax of `Bigfunction` is incorrect. You cannot have multiple `return` statements

Comment: Return means the function end...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [lambda](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-expressions) and [map](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) function.

```
def Bigfunction(G,T):
    return list(map(lambda x:0.03*x,G)),list(map(lambda x,y:(x/1000)*(y-25),G,[T]*len(G))), list(map(lambda x:x/800,G))
G = list(range(100,1100,100))
T1, I1, I2 = Bigfunction(G,25)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot mentioning about lambda and map. It worked for me when i used T = 25. It gave output. But, when I gave a list of T values, it gives error. After your response, I have modified the question above and please, look into to know what is the error.

Comment: @ Msquae, the reason behind is that I use [T]*len(G) to make a list for the lambda function to iterate. U can simple take out [] and make it T*len(G) and it will work again.

Comment: Excellent. It worked. I am new to Python and thanks for helping me.

Comment: @Msquare, no problem.

Comment: I have one more question here. Now, i don't give T input to the Bigfunction. Now it will be defined as `def Bigfunction(G)`. But, inside the function, first subfunction gives me T and I want to use it in the third subfunction where I require T. Is it possible?

Comment: I have modified the question. Could you check it and reply me the mistake in code.

Comment: @Msquare, the reason why it is only two items. Because first list Gyou have 11 items and second list T you only have 2 items. So  map only iterate 2 items hence give you two items. To get more items you need to enlarge second list, make it 10 with list(map(lambda x,y:(x/1000)*(1 + (y-25)),G,T*(len(G)//len(T)))).

Comment: @ Msquare, It is possible, you can check some online examples on higher order functions or wrapper function. You basically need a function object to store the value your called.

Comment: I found the mistake. That is, `T = list(range(25,35,10))`. I thought, it would give a list of 10 values sandwiched between 25, 35. Instead, it gave two only. Now, I changed it to `T = np.linspace(25,40,10)`Now, I got ten values of T. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You try to return multiple values but you do not use the correct syntax. Try this:

```
def Bigfunction(G, T):
    return 0.03 * G, (G / 1000) * (T - 25), G / 800


T1 = []
T2 = []
T3 = []
for G in range(100, 1100, 100):
    a, b, c = Bigfunction(G, 25)
    T1.append(a)
    T2.append(b)
    T3.append(c)
```

Comment: Incorrect, G is a list, you have to iterate over it.

Comment: I did not even see that, fixed it

Answer (score 0):

I think it's better to define 3 separate functions for the calculations as you've done first. However, I would give them more descriptive names according to what they do. This way you'll be able to combine them as you want or even call them from other modules.

For instance:

```
def solar_current(G):
    return 0.03*G # Solar cell photo current in A

def shorcircuit_current(G,T):
    return (G/1000)*(T-25)  # short circuit current

def f3(G): # Whatever name it describes a bit better what it does.
    return G/800

T1, I1, I2 = [], [], []
for G in range(100, 1100, 100):
    T1.append(solar_current(G))
    I1.append(shortcircuit_current(G, 25))
    I2.append(f3(G))
```

PS: I assume the `25` you're passing as T value is an example. With the calculations done in `shortcuit_current()` it will always return 0